# How can I redirect from my login page to :8000/username in Django

Tags: django, authentication

i have my login form in the homepage itself i.e. "/". now from there i want to redirect a user to 0.0.0.0:8000/username where 'username' is not static, it i different for different users.
I'm a beginner to Django. Pls explain in dept. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

what you could do is define a home url and a profile url in your urls.py like this.

```
#urls.py
url(r'^$', 'app.views.home'),
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'app.views.profile'),
```

now under views.py define 2 views one to render the home page and second to render the profile page

```
# views.py

import models
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.templates import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def home(request):
    """
    this is the landing page for your application.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username, password = request.POST['username'], request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user is None:
            login(request, user)
            # send a successful login message here
        else:
            # Send an Invalid Username or password message here
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # Redirect to profile page
        redirect('/%s/' % request.user.username)
    else:
        # Show the homepage with login form
        return render_to_response('home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def profile(request, username):
    """
    This view renders a user's profile
    """

    user = user.objects.get(username=username)
    render_to_response('profile.html', { 'user' : user})
```

Now when the first url `/` is requested it forwards the request to `app.views.home` which means the home view ===within===> views.py ===within===> `app` application.

the home view checks if a user is authenticated or not. if a user is authenticated it calls the url `/username` otherwise it simply renders a template called `home.html` in your templates directory.

The profile view accepts 2 arguments, 1. request and 2. username. Now, when the profile view is called with the above mentioned arguments it gets the user instance for the username provided and stores it in a `user` variable and later passes it to the `profile.html` template.

also please do read through the very easy [Poll Application Tutorial on Django Project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) to get familiar with the power of django.

:)

Comment: But, the problem is when i click on submit at '/' where do it directs i.e. what would be in action="?".

Comment: it depends where you want to process the login, leave the `action=` attribute empty. if you want the home view to the handle the login. I have update the answer to handle the login on form post and then redirect a user. have a look.

Comment: thanks, solved problem.......I was having problem in my url pattens' order. I kept the dynamic url at end and it solved the problem

Comment: you may want to tick the answer, if it was of any help. thanks.